# Hibernate inheritance: Schema-validation: missing column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, database-schema

I am trying to implement inheritance in `Hibernate` with strategy `InheritanceType.JOINED`. However, when starting up the application it fails with the exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [EMAIL] in table [CLIENT]
```

I don't know why it is looking for the field `email` in the `Client` table, since the entity model specifies it is in the abstract superclass - `User`. Client has only fields specific for it.

Here is how my entity model looks.

**UserTable.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class UserTable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserTablePK userTablePK;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 512)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME", nullable = false, length = 256)
    private String firstName;

    public UserTable() {
    }

    public UserTable(Long userId, String email, String password, String firstName) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userTablePK = new UserTablePK(email);
        this.password = HashCalculator.calculateSha256Hash(password, SecurityConstants.saltConstant());
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
// get, set
}
```

**UserTablePK.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class UserTablePK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false, length = 256)
    private String email;

    public UserTablePK() {
    }

    public UserTablePK(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
```

**ClientTable.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public class ClientTable extends UserTable implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "WEIGHT")
    private String weight;

    @Column(name = "HEIGHT")
    private Integer height;

    public ClientTable() {
    }

    public ClientTable(Long clientId, String weight, Integer height, String email, String password, String firstName) {
        super(clientId, email, password, firstName);
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

Again, why is it looking for `email` field in the subclass table? I used Liquibase for Schema generation, and I checked - the schema is correct. There is no `email` in the `Client` table, it's only in the `User` table as it should be. The entity model corresponds to that, so what's the issue?

Comment: why have a separate PK class just to contain a single field?! let's complicate life ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's the pk in the parent class .... You need to refer to the parent table from the child table, hence you also need an 'email' column in the child table to refer through it back to the parent table

EDIT : You will just need to add a column "email" in 'CLIENT' table to just use the JPA default config .... if you want to edit the FK that references from child to parent you will need to override @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn as described [here](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance)

Comment: I kind of got the idea, but not sure how you mean really. Could you please provide a code sample?